# Where do zimlets store their UserProperties?

Tags: zimbra

So you've defined some properties in your zimlet, both in the XML file and via the .properties file. But suppose you change your mind and decide to remove some properties, how would you do so ? removing them from the files, and even removing the complete files won't remove the properties from the property editor, it's kind of persistant somewhere. Is there a way to sort of reset the zimlet ?

I also checked that they were not stored neither in the cookies nor the mysql database.

Any idea ? maybe LDAP ? if so, can you suggest a way to search for them ?

Answer (score 2):

They're stored in the LDAP directory, you can list them via the zmprov command

```
zmprov ga yassine@myhost.tld | grep zimbraZimletUserProperties | grep com_feeder_sugarbee
zimbraZimletUserProperties: com_feeder_sugarbee:username:
zimbraZimletUserProperties: com_feeder_sugarbee:user:
zimbraZimletUserProperties: com_feeder_sugarbee:passwd:
zimbraZimletUserProperties: com_feeder_sugarbee:password:
```

I don't know if it's a flaw in the Zimlets framework design or not, but the framework should give the developer the proper tools to both define and undefine properties, instead of forcing him to ask the the admin to remove properties for him :(

http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zmprov gives an example on how to define and remove properties (didn't try it yet) :

```
zmprov ma user1 +zimbraZimletUserProperties "com_company_testing:favoriteColor:blue"
```

(the remove part should really be just - instead of +)